# How to Set Android Project as a Sub-Project in Intellij Idea Using Gradle

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle project with two sub-modules: One is named `web` for the web interface and one is named `server` for the server side application. 
The `settings.gradle` file:

```
include ':myapp-app'
rootProject.name = 'myapp'

include 'web'
include 'server'
```

Next, I would like to have an Android module along with the other two. So my questions is what is the correct way add the android project?

- Should I just add a `include 'android-app'` entry into the `settings.gradle` file, and appropriate `build.gradle` and other environment files?
- Should I create the project manually using Idea?  Right click on the module -> Create new Android project?
- Should I create a completely new project for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just create a new module and add it as dependence using android studio